# How to check f is surjective

Tags: functions, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function s.t $|f(x)-f(y)|\ge \frac{1}{2}|x-y|$ for all $x,y$.
Then $f$ is injective can be seen easily as $x\neq y$ implies $f(x)\neq f(y)$. 
But how to check that $f$ is surjective or not ?

Answer (score 3):

Let $a\in\Bbb R$, $r=|a-f(0)|$. Then $|f(\pm 3r)-f(0)|\ge \frac 32r$. Observe that $f(\pm3r)$ cannot be on the same side of $f(0)$, hence $f(-3r)<a<f(3r)$ or $f(-3r)>a>f(3r)$.

Comment: You need $a \ne f(0)$ for this to work.

Comment: Luckily, the case $a = f(0)$ is not too hard.

Comment: @Bib-lost: I grant you that :-)

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is injective and it's easy to see that $f^{-1}:imf\to \mathbb R$ is continuous, so $f:\mathbb R\to imf$ is a homeomorphism.

Now it suffices to note that $imf$ is connected and clopen. The result follows because the only clopen, connected set in $\mathbb R$ with the usual topology is $\mathbb R$ itself.